# CGImageRef Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Maybe this a newbie question, but according to my instruments there is a leak there, but im releasing the imageRef. i cant figure it out. its a category function.

```
-(UIImage *)imageAtRect:(CGRect)rect
{

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
UIImage* subImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
return subImage;

}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, which line does Instruments mark ?

Comment: CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);

Comment: answered my own question below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out instruments flags the line where the leaked object is created. i am calling this function within another function that returns an UIImage (which is leaked, but doesn't show on  instruments) , i just set it to autorelease and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
[self CGImage]
```

?

Comment: its a category function. so self is UIImage